# Can anybody explain me clearly that how to get ubuntu TV working..?

Tags: hdmi, tv, ubuntu-tv

I have Samsung Smart TV 40 inch.. Smart HUB doesn't feel as good as Ubuntu TV, and I was wondering to install Ubuntu on my TV..But now I am not understanding the concept of Ubuntu TV clearly..I mean ..if I install Ubuntu TV on my PC and connect it to my TV using HDMI then how I will be able to use remote to control Ubuntu TV..so if anyone can explain me..then please...do it now..I am totally confused..!

Here i am writing what i understood of ubuntu tv..i think its wrong but it is askUbuntu thats why I am asking .." Ubuntu to be install on a pendrive and then plug it in smart tv then install Ubuntu TV on my TV.."

Answer (score 1):

I understood everything very clearly NOW from this site..

http://en.the-ghost.com/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-on-any-tv.html

iT is not so good..I mean I will need to use 2 devices to run 1 device/..